# How to make Animations in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a similar project with what this guy has made [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00AzqWdF--s)

Of course, not that awesome, it is way beyond my skills. But what I am trying to make now is very simple (compared to the video)

this is what I have done so far [image: Image 1]

This is what I've made,  With Drag and drop of course, cant figure out how to create a shape (Rectangle or any other shape) in a short distance from the specific button, and then connected with an other shape or something similar.

This what I've done is just when you press the button to show those two Rectangles.

Also, trying to make it in different Angles too. for example like in this pic

[image: Image 2]

To give you a better understanding in the project I am making, please read bellow.

This is a school project I am making, I have some data in a database in SQL and want to demonstrate those not in a table or any label, but as in the photos I show you. For example. When the form loads, it gets the first row, and lists items like Name (will be the button) then the other rectangles will be created from the information listed. for example. When you click the Name of the person(button) it will show 2-3 Rectangles(the green rectangles) with the labels of Age, School, Gender or anything else.

[image: Image 3]

How can I do this? Is it able to be done? I know its really hard, but can any one refer me in any tutorial for this? What I've searched on google, most of the tutorials are outdated, 6-7 years old.

Thanks for your Consideration

Comment: I retracted my close vote as too broad with the question of, is the amount of objects animated out for each button consistent and static?

Comment: I understand, its your decision. Still looking for some help. But if many people will vote to close this or delete it, I will be forced to take this down..

Comment: The amount of object wont be more than 6-7 things which will contain Student personal details. Will be static, not dragable .

Comment: So the parts that take a reasonable amount of time, is handling a dynamic number of animated flyout stuff for each button, and handling stuff like z-index depending on how they're displayed. If you'd like a templated example of how to just make a button make stuff animate out like your example, I could provide that in minutes but complexity beyond that is the type of thing I make a living with. ;)

Comment: PS I believe the style of visualization you're showing is called node-link diagram. Though I don't know of any decent free one's out there for wpf.

Comment: Yes please, that would be very helpful to me sir. The temptation of paying you for something complex like that is very high, because it will save me much time, and focus more in the SQL part. how it will create a new button for each student and stuff. But the temptation of not eating only Ramen for the rest of the month is very high too. Maybe by the end of the month when I get my payment might think for something out... But thanks for the template you are going to give me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: PS: there is http://www.graphviz.org/ or http://www.dalssoft.com/diagram/ diagram.net which are open source and free

Comment: Haha no worries man, SO isn't about paying anybody, it's about learning while helping others learn, but once something gets into hours well we all have lives on the other side of the screen, and many of us lived off ramen while learning too, including myself. Give me a minute to finish what I'm working on and I'll plop out something for you. In the interim though, generally folks expect to see any effort of your own first so we both are breaking the status quo a bit lol.

Comment: Neither of those are WPF I don't think but I'll look again here in a min. :)

Comment: It looks like its really hard for a pro like you.. Imagine what it would take me..

Comment: @ChrisW. Im trying to make something like this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FkRzDegzAo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya I know what you're trying to accomplish, but like I said it's the type of reason places hire specialty front-end "devigner" guys to make that stuff.

So I apologize for the delayed response but I had to get my normal workday stuff out of the way first, and I spent about 15mins on this little example before I head off for the day soon to get you started with an idea or two.

I did however leave out the Exit actions for when Toggle IsChecked=False. There's also a lot of other ways I might do things if it was my project but something like this could eat up most of a day or more real easily (especially depending how cool you make it) so this is just a pseudo example but I hope it helps.

[image]

**As a ToggleButton template (SUPER SIMPLE CONCEPT EXAMPLE);**

```
<ToggleButton Content="Boaty McBoatFace" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>

                        <Storyboard x:Key="bubbleAnim">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble1">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="55"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble1">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="55"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble2">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="55"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble3">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="210"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble3">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="55"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble4">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="210"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble4">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="133"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble5">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="210"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble5">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="205"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble6">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="205"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble6">
                                <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="-5"/>
                            </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble7">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="55"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble7">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="205"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble8">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="55"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble8">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="133"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble1">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble2">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble3">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble4">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble5">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble6">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0.985"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble7">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="bubble8">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="line1">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="line2">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="line3">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="line4">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="line5">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="line6">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="line7">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="line8">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>

                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                    <Border Height="300" Width="300">
                        <Canvas>
                            <Canvas.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="Line">
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
                                </Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Border">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Purple"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="50"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5"/>
                                </Style>
                            </Canvas.Resources>

                            <Line x:Name="line1" Opacity="0" 
                                      X1="75" Y1="75"
                                      X2="150" Y2="150"/>
                            <Line x:Name="line2" Opacity="0"
                                      X1="150" Y1="75"
                                      X2="150" Y2="150" Stroke="Blue"/>
                            <Line x:Name="line3" Opacity="0"
                                      X1="225" Y1="75"
                                      X2="150" Y2="150"/>
                            <Line x:Name="line4" Opacity="0"
                                      X1="225" Y1="150"
                                      X2="150" Y2="150" Stroke="Blue"/>
                            <Line x:Name="line5" Opacity="0"
                                      X1="150" Y1="150"
                                      X2="75" Y2="225"/>
                            <Line x:Name="line6" Opacity="0"
                                      X1="150" Y1="150"
                                      X2="150" Y2="225" Stroke="Blue"/>
                            <Line x:Name="line7" Opacity="0"
                                      X1="150" Y1="150"
                                      X2="225" Y2="225"/>
                            <Line x:Name="line8" Opacity="0"
                                      X1="150" Y1="150"
                                      X2="75" Y2="150" Stroke="Blue"/>


                            <Border x:Name="bubble1" Opacity="0"
                                    Canvas.Left="133" Canvas.Top="134">
                                <TextBlock Text="1"/>
                            </Border>

                            <Border x:Name="bubble2" Opacity="0"
                                    Canvas.Left="133" Canvas.Top="134">
                                <TextBlock Text="2"/>
                            </Border>

                            <Border x:Name="bubble3" Opacity="0"
                                    Canvas.Left="133" Canvas.Top="134">
                                <TextBlock Text="3"/>
                            </Border>

                            <Border x:Name="bubble4" Opacity="0"
                                    Canvas.Left="133" Canvas.Top="134">
                                <TextBlock Text="4"/>
                            </Border>

                            <Border x:Name="bubble5" Opacity="0"
                                    Canvas.Left="133" Canvas.Top="134">
                                <TextBlock Text="5"/>
                            </Border>

                            <Border x:Name="bubble6" Opacity="0"
                                    Canvas.Left="133" Canvas.Top="134">
                                <TextBlock Text="6"/>
                            </Border>

                            <Border x:Name="bubble7" Opacity="0"
                                    Canvas.Left="133" Canvas.Top="134">
                                <TextBlock Text="7"/>
                            </Border>

                            <Border x:Name="bubble8" Opacity="0"
                                    Canvas.Left="133" Canvas.Top="134">
                                <TextBlock Text="8"/>
                            </Border>

                            <Border CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    Canvas.Left="95" Canvas.Top="138" Padding="1">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>


                        </Canvas>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource bubbleAnim}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>
        </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: You're a genius Chris! btw, how to do it when click somewhere else, those to close again?

Comment: Also, have been unable to edit the text of the button "Boaty McBoatFace". 
I mean, to change the name of the button from a text box. The button to take the value of the text

Comment: There's nothing genius going on here, it's a pretty minimal example. You can change the text by changing the `Content` property on the first line. Also like I said, I left out any ExitActions. What you're trying to do overall can easily become a considerably time consuming thing which honestly I can't volunteer for at this point in time. This example was just meant to get some creative juices flowing for ya so you could pick up from here. :)

Comment: Its really good, thanks. It gave me the point of the idea how to continue it. 
but I have an other question. it is too little to create a new post so was hopping you to help me. How to change the background color of my window? I'm trying to make a random color changer for the background. controlled by a timer, but looks like timer is not in my Tools.. why?

Comment: That's the type of thing I'm sure google could provide some answers for first. Give some things a shot and come on back when run into a blocker with another question. :)